# IFrame issue in CGridView pagination - Yii Framework

Tags: javascript, iframe, yii

I am trying to call ajax() Post to save a method in iFrame design. Iframe design contains cgridview, I am facing issue in pagination after use document write in Iframe content on "Ajax onsuccess".

Ajax Post code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',                           
            url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("form/FormResponse"); ?>',
        data: responsedata,
        success:function(data){
            var iframe = document.getElementById('cru-frame-resgrid');
            if(data !='')
        {
                                             iframe.contentWindow.document.write(data); // writing content to iframe here
                                     iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
                                    }                                   
                                    },
                                   error: function(data) { // if error occured


                                    },

                                  dataType:'html'
                                  });
```

Controller Code:

```
public function actionFormResponse()
{
 ............
 ............
 echo $this->renderPartial('response',array(               'model'=>$model,'base'=>$model->crm_base_contact_form_id,'tabid'=>$model->st_tabno,'quesid'=>$model->crm_campaign_script_question_id,
  )); 
}
```

This renderpartial not rendering page its comes to ajax onsuccess so i wrote this code to add content in iframe but am facing pagination issue after writing data to it,

```
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(data); // writing content to iframe here

iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
```

Please anyone guide me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can render your view with render method using some empty layout. Using this trick helps you to render gridview js-scripts. Also you may use scriptMap to exclude unwanted script rendering:

```
$cs=Yii::app()->clientScript;
$cs->scriptMap=array(
        'jquery.js'=>false,
        'jquery.min.js'=>false
);
```

Comment: Still facing CgridView pagination error "undefined index:base". echo $this->renderPartial('response',array(               'model'=>$model,'base'=>$model->crm_base_contact_form_id,'tabid'=>$model->st_tabno,'quesid'=>$model->crm_campaign_script_question_id,
  ));

Comment: First time cgridview pagination works fine. after writing content to iframe on ajaxsuccess cgridview pagination not working for rendered view. If could take parameters properly while navigating

Comment: $_POST array is empty so am getting pagination error as undefined index